# Algebraic simplification into difference of squares

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I have an equation of the form:

$$
f(x) = x^2 + y^2 - (r+1) xy
$$

where $r > 0$.

I want to write this into the difference of squares form: $(A - B)^2$. I have tried to rewrite this into:

$$
f(x) = (x-y)^2 + (1-r)xy
$$

I am stuck with the term $(1-r)xy$. Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions? Otherwise, one could write $$f(x) = \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - (r+1) xy} - 0\right)^2$$

Comment: If you want only real coefficients this would be impossible. Any $(A-B)^2$ would be non-negative, but this is not the case for $x=y=1,r=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you call it $f(x)$, not $f(x,y)$ or $f(x,y,r)$, I am going to assume that $x$ is more important than $y$. I suggest treating $y,r$ as constants and completing the square on $x$:
$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2 - (r+1)xy &= x^2 -2\dfrac{(r+1)y}2x + \dfrac{(r+1)^2y^2}4 +y^2-\dfrac{(r+1)^2y^2}4 \\&= \left(x - \dfrac{(r+1)y}2\right)^2 - \left(y\sqrt{\dfrac{(r+1)^2}4-1}\right)^2\end{align}$$

This still requires $r \ge 1$ to be strictly real.